# What tool can visualize metadata from many photos on a Mac?

Tags: software, metadata, statistics

I have seen/heard about a PC/Unix (??) utility that goes through *all* your JPG/RAW pictures on your disk and shows you on a graph

- your most used lens,
- your most used zoom range,
- flash settings etc...

-- anything you can get from your camera data include in picture.

But I'm looking for a good utility that works on a Mac...

---

Also Asked by [Eruditass](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/389/eruditass):

What are the best EXIF analyzer tools to give you statistics and pretty graphs with information such as:

- Lens
- Camera
- Focal Length
- Aperture
- Shutter Speed
- ISO
- Date

  - Time of Day
  - Day of Week
- Exposure Mode
- Focus Distance
- Processing Lag (Date Modified - Date Taken)

Do any **support DNG** / RAW? Are any open source?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know of [Exposure Plot](http://www.cpr.demon.nl/prog_plotf.html) ExposurePlot on PC, it's pretty nice and free.

[image]

Is your question that you are looking for one on Mac? Someone asked in [DPReview forum](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1017&message=22083403&changemode=1) but not much came out of it. Someone elsewhere is using [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) to run a Windows XP virtual machine and use Exposure Plot from it.

Comment: Aw, JPEG only? Any ones that support DNG?

Comment: You may be able to run it under WINE.

Comment: [Photostats](http://hierzo.net/) has an OSX version.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a program *specifically* for that purpose, but Adobe Photoshop Lightroom allows for filtering by various bits of info including lens model, focal length, and so on.  It will allow you to see the number of photos for a particular bit of information although it's not presented graphically.

Comment: Assuming the field you want isn't one of those in the *maker notes* section that Adobe products **totally ignore**.

Answer (score 2):

["Aperture Inspector"](http://apertureinspector.com/) extracts this information from an Apple Aperture library.

Comment: This link doesn't seem to take you directly to the software, but I've not been able to find a direct link myself...

Comment: It used to.  I can't find any trace of it on the site now - it's possibly not being sold any more.  It's still on MacUpdate: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36133/aperture-inspector , but if it isn't being supported it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Link is now updated.

Answer (score 2):

[Photostats](http://hierzo.net/) is very similar to ExposurePlot. There are versions for Windows and OSX. The OSX version can use a Lightroom or iPhoto catalog to create charts. I'm not affiliated with the tool in any way, just found it once when looking to see if there was an OSX version of ExposurePlot.

Answer (score 2):

If you have been using Aperture, you can export the metadata as a text file then input it into excel and do whatever graphs you want:

Select your pics. File /Export Metadata. Then you have a tab-delimited txt file you can import in Excel. Then use the Dynamic table feature from Excel

Comment: Could you perhaps explain how one can export the metadata to Excel?

Comment: Select your pics. File /Export Metadata. Then you have a tab-delimited txt file you can import in excel. Then use the Dynamic table feature

Comment: Great, can you edit your answer to include that information? Also, what software are you using when you click File /Export Metadata?

Comment: Oh, sorry; I thought we were speaking in the context of Aperture. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Aperture's **Smart Albums** to get this information out, but you'll only get one data point at a time, so it can be a slow process if you want detailed stats.

You can make Smart Albums that search for photos by any of the EXIF/IPTC data (camera body, lens, focal length, aperture, shutter speed, iso, ...) and see how many photos match the search.