# What software can show my most frequently used focal length?

Tags: software, metadata, prime, focal-length, statistics

Many people recommend a focal length of 35mm, 50mm, and sometimes even 85mm and upwards for those interested in purchasing a prime lens. I, however, would like to figure out what focal length(s) I use most often, and then purchase a prime with that approximate focal length.

Is there a piece of software that will analyze thousands of photos and then tell me how many times I used a certain focal length?

Comment: What operating system(s) are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, which does have some compatibility options

Comment: This question is substantially like http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5311/1356 .

Comment: I think you're right - should they be merged?  I'm sorry about the duplicate question, but I think the title of that question wasn't very clear.

Comment: If anything, that question should be merged into this one.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: when I borrowed a friend's 24-70mm zoom for a while, my most frequently-used focal lengths were 24mm and 70mm. That doesn't mean that those were really the focal lengths I wanted most, just that for whatever reason I found it most natural to go to the zoom extremes. If I had shot for a while with a selection of zooms, I suspect that the data would be highly biased towards whatever focal lengths happened to be at the ends of those lenses' ranges.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Someone referred me once to [Exposure Plot](http://www.vandel.nl/exposureplot.html). This is a **free** Windows utility which is very simple. It shows you graphs of different parameters, one of them being focal-length.

If you already use image management application like **Lightroom** or **Bibble Pro**, then you can also usually see that data in the *filter* interface.

For Lightroom for example, you need to activate the filter bar (/), select *Metadata* and change one of the columns to show *Focal-Length*. You'll get to see all the focal-lengths used and the number of photos taken at each focal-length. What's neat is that you can combine things like rating and focal-length, to find out which focal-length is used in your best images.

Comment: Exposure Plot only supports JPEG

Comment: Maybe time to update the Bibble Pro reference?

Answer (score 11):

I believe [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) can be used to produce this kind of analysis, but it requires some technical command-line knowledge.

For example, see this: http://www.flickr.com/photos/code_martial/3280664879/

Comment: Well, it's a start, but not quite as user-friendly as I had in mind. Thanks, though.

Comment: Itai's answer (exposure plot) looks much more user friendly, but I think it may be jpeg only? I may try both later. If I do, I can write up a short guide on how to get exiftool working.

Comment: If you want to go the exiftool route, I have a script that may help; see http://reidster.net/software/

Comment: exiftoolgui now does internal graphing and recursive search, no scripting required.

Comment: I tested that exif doesn't work for CR2, but exiftool certainly does today.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that:

- The focal length has been recorded in the file metadata
- You are running a Unix-like OS such as Linux or OS X (or Cygwin in Windows)
- You have installed the [exif command line tool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

Run this on the command line:

```
exif /path/to/your/photos/* | grep "Focal Length [^A-Za-z]*|" \ 
 | awk -F "|" '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Note that the `exif` command may have a different name on your system such as `exiftool`.

Also, note that you may have to change the file search pattern immediately after the `exif` command name to match only relevant images. For example, if you are shooting RAW+JPEG, change that to `/path/to/your/photos/*.jpeg`

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Note that this may need to be tailored to your particular install.  A few things which helped me:  1) The default tool command is 'exiftool' not 'exif 2) If you have a set of nested directories, you can have exiftool recursively process them using the -r option 3) If there are multiple fields which include 'Focal Length', you will need to specify. For example, this worked for me:  `$  exiftool -r /Users/myuser/Pictures/iPhoto\ Library.photolibrary/Masters/2016* | grep "^Focal Length In 35mm Format" | awk -F ": " '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 7):

For Lightroom users, Jeffrey Friedl's Data Plot plugin is great...
http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/data-plot

What's nice about that is being able to filter your photos in Lightroom, keepers, 5 star rated, certain lenses, whatever, then seeing the focal lengths for just those photos.

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of ExifToolGUI supports graphing and recursive search !
[image]

http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,2750.0.html

http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/~bogdan/

https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Lightroom, without any additional software.

In the Library module, if you select your entire library of photos, and then click on the **Metadata** Library Filter, you can add a column to the display, and if you click on the title of the column, you can then select **Focal Length**. All the focal lengths you use will be listed, with the number of occurrences in the selection.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Lightroom, then [Lightroom Analytics](http://lightroomanalytics.com/) is a tremendously useful tool to analyse your settings in camera and lightroom. It's all exported as a spreadsheet and can also be viewed in the included web browser based viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another option for *nix users. This will count the totals for each focal length for all CR2 files in a directory and subdirectories. I'm guessing this will work for other image formats as well, but I have not tried it.

Requirements:

- Linux/Unix system (I've only done this on Arch, but it shouldn't matter)
- `exiv2` package - Reads image metadata.
- `pv` package - Optional, if you want to have a progress bar. It took a couple minutes to get through about 4,000 files on my machine, so it was nice to have.

And here it is:

```
find -iname '*.cr2' -print0 \
 | while read -d $'\0' f; do \
     exiv2 -K Exif.Photo.FocalLength -P t "$f" 2> /dev/null; done \
 | pv -l -s $(find -iname '*.cr2' -printf '.' | wc -c) \
 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Explanation, for those who are curious:

- `find -iname '*.cr2'` Gets a list of all the .CR2 files. The `-print0` option changes the delimiter to a null character instead of a newline, to avoid issues in the unlikely event that there is a newline within a filename.
- `while read -d $'\0' f; do ... done` Loops through the output from the `find` command, again delimited by a null character.
- `exiv2 -K Exif.Photo.FocalLength -P t "$f"` Reads the metadata for each file, specifically outputting the focal length. Appending `2> /dev/null` suppresses errors. I added this because I was getting a lot of unimportant warnings.
- `pv -l -s $(find -iname '*.cr2' -printf '.' | wc -c)` Shows a progress bar, which comes in handy when going through thousands of files. The `find ... | wc -c` subcommand here tells the `pv` command the total number of files so it can calculate the progress.
- `sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` Sorts the list of focal lengths, counts occurrences of each focal length, sorts the results by occurrence count.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.whichprimelens.com/. You can drag folders into the UI and it'll plot out your focal lengths. Only works with JPGs though.

[image: whichprimelens plot]

Answer (score 0):

<sup>**Prerequisites:** PowerShell (so: Windows), [exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). May work on other OSs with [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/powershell/powershell#get-powershell), and with `exiftool` instead of `exiftool.exe`.</sup>

I was about to write a tool myself when I encountered [Alex Jensen's post](https://www.cron.dk/playing-with-exif/):

Open up a PowerShell terminal and copy and paste your way through this:

> For those not used to code: Lines beginning with a # mark a comment line. As you can see, more than half of everything is comments, so keep calm! :)

```
# Let exiftool collect all EXIF-data from a directory (recursively) and save it in a .CSV-file:
C:\temp\exiftool.exe "Z:\Pics" -csv -r -ext NRW -ext CR2 -ext JPG -ISO -ISOSetting -Aperture -ExposureTime -Model -Lens -FocalLength -LensID -ExposureCompensation -MeteringMode -Flash -FocusMode -AFAreaMode -CreateDate > c:\temp\all_exif.csv
# Note: C:\temp\exiftool.exe ... path to your exiftool.exe
# Note: Z:\Pics ... path to your pictures
# Note: C:\temp\all_exif.csv ... basically any place on your computer.
# Note: -ext can be adapted (e.g. add -ext ARW and remove -ext CR2)
# Note: It gets a lot of metadata, not only focal length. You could delete all but -FocalLength if you want to.

# You could now import that .CSV-file into Excel or any other spreadsheet program - or you keep going with your PowerShell window:

# Load the exifdata to a variable for further manipulation:
$exif = Import-Csv c:\temp\all_exif.csv

# Get information about focal length:
$exif | Group-Object Focallength -NoElement

# Different other metadata:
# Apertures used:
$exif | Group-Object Aperture -NoElement
# Show all lenses ever used:
$exif | Group-Object LensID | Select-Object Name | Sort-Object Name
# Find the most used combination of ISO and Aperture:
$exif | Group-Object ISO, Aperture | Sort-Object count -Descending | Select-Object Count, name
```