# Software to display statistics based on EXIF data?

Tags: software, metadata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What software can show my most frequently used focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7268/what-software-can-show-my-most-frequently-used-focal-length)

I'm interested in learning what the photo settings i use the most often (eg. what focal length, what ISO etc.) to possibly help with deciding what lens to get in the future. Is there any software (or a simple script) that will enumerate all my photos and produce a report based on EXIF data? Something that will for example list the number of photos for taken at each ISO setting or (possibly more useful) a lsit of how many photos at each focal length.

Comment: @mattdm agreed and the answer list looks about the same. Could that question possibly be updated to be more generic and encompass this question aswell? Otheerwise we may get someone asking what tool can i use for ISO, what tool can i use for shutter speed etc...

Comment: You can also use Adobe Bridge, Filter Tab to sort all kinds of different EXIF data!

Comment: @mundeep: since the existing answers to that question _do_ cover those sorts of things, I don't see why not.

Comment: @mattdm: i've posted a question on meta http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2061/if-the-answers-to-a-specific-question-also-satisfies-the-answer-to-a-generic-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help you : http://www.cpr.demon.nl/prog_plotf.html . It's (ExposurePlot) a Windows freeware.

I hadn't tested it but according to his description it allow to

> generates statistical graphs for exposure information, contained in
>   the EXIF data of digital photos. It analyzes focal length, ISO,
>   aperture (F-Stop) and shutter speed and generates graphs that display
>   the percentage used, times used and combinations of these values

Comment: Hi maxmouchet. Thank you for the answer, but we discourage simply linking to other content here, to prevent loss of information in case the link dies, and also so everyone doesn't have to click the link to figure out what your answer is. If you could write a short summary of what the link is to, that would be very much appreciated. Thank you for the contribution and welcome!

Comment: I understand, I corrected my answer.

Comment: This works great, very specific tool but the graphs help make it easy to see any trends and not have to put the numbers from Lightroom into Excel :)

Answer (score 4):

I use the **filter bar in Adobe Photoshop Lightroom**. This gives you the option to filter by metadata such as camera used or lens used. It is a dropdown when you are in the Library mode, and you can highlight one or multiple lenses, ISO settings, focal length, Aperture, and the list goes on and on. [This](http://lightroom-news.com/2008/04/02/metadata-filtering-in-lightroom-20/) is an example of what the filters look like and how to use them.

If you do not have Lightroom you can download a free trial that is fully functional to test this feature out are the [Lightroom website](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=photoshop_lightroom).

Comment: Just installed the trial and it looks quite good, it's just missing the pretty graphs that ExposurePlot gives which is why i went with it instead :)

Comment: There is also a focal-length sort plugin and some other analysis plugins by Jeffrey Friedl: http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/focal-length-sort

Comment: @mundeep - It does a few other things too if you aren't just interested in EXIF data ;)

Comment: @dpollitt sure does, for example you can filter on multiple exif data at once. One drawback however is that it gives the raw focal length whereas the ExplosurePlot converts everything to the 35mm equivalent which helps when you have images from multiple cameras.

Answer (score 0):

google "ExifTool by Phil Harvey", it is a very powerful tool that can extract and modify EXIF information. It has a number of reports, and can easily be built into additional tools using the standard Unix-style piping. You could even pipe data into a database or statistical package, such as R