# What EXIF analyzer tools give statistics and pretty graphs?

Tags: software, metadata, open-source, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool can visualize metadata from many photos on a Mac?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5311/what-tool-can-visualize-metadata-from-many-photos-on-a-mac)

What are the best EXIF analyzer tools to give you statistics and pretty graphs with information such as:

- Lens
- Camera
- Focal Length
- Aperture
- Shutter Speed
- ISO
- Date

  - Time of Day
  - Day of Week
- Exposure Mode
- Focus Distance
- Processing Lag (Date Modified - Date Taken)

Do any **support DNG** / RAW? Are any open source?

Comment: This is a more general form of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7268/what-software-can-show-my-most-frequently-used-focal-length and actually a more-coherently phrased but exact duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5311/analyze-and-see-your-inside-photo-info