# What free software can I use to find pictures through meta data on Linux?

Tags: software, metadata, linux

I am looking for a software that allows me to find in my collection pictures that have a particular characteristic. For example pictures taken with the same lenses and similar focal length. or find pictures taken in a particular time frame.

Is there something like this for free (or very low price)? I would like it to run under Linux (via wine if necessary).

Comment: Take a look at http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7268/what-software-can-show-my-most-frequently-used-focal-length and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5311/what-tool-can-visualize-metadata-from-many-photos-on-a-mac. Neither of those questions really got great answers (although maybe you'll find something helpful there); maybe this whole concept would do better on http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want free, and cross platform, you could try [MaPiVi](http://mapivi.sourceforge.net/mapivi.shtml) or [XnView](http://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=24056).  MaPiVi only seems to work with JPG files, so if you shoot RAW it won't work for you. But you can search EXIF data like ISO, camera, shutter speed, and date/time.

Most catalogueing software will allow you to search or filter by EXIF data to some degree. You'd have to trial specific ones to see if they do all that you need.

Comment: xnview seems to have what I need right now. thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at our [Daminion](http://daminion.net) or [Lightroom](http://adobe.com). Both photo managers allow to extract and display Camera lens along with some other technical information (focal length, camera model, date taken, ISO, shutter speed, etc...).

Daminion is free, Lightroom costs $299.

Comment: looks good, but unfortunately it doesnt work under wine (at least not out of the box)

Comment: We doesn't tested it under Wine yet. Probably it will be possible in the future.

Comment: @santiagozky But you can use it with VirtualBox. :)